# Data Loader Stuck

Tags: data-loader

when I am using the data loader I going to insert and browse the report file to object.
It’s always showing this pop up box “initializing salesforce object and csv file”. I am unable to move forward. Please help me.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the .csv?

Comment: 103 records and 47 fields

Comment: you can move report file using eclipse tool.

Comment: is data loader wont work for reports?

Comment: @ravikant we can move report file using eclipse but records also to be move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I used the salesforce export csv file and at the bottom of the csv it had junk values such as the name of the report and the salesforce copyright info.  Just delete.

Sample output at end of the CSV

---

ReportNameXXXXXXXXXX
Copyright (c) 2000-2016 salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved.
Confidential Information - Do Not Distribute
Generated By: Admin  5/16/2016 2:38 PM

Comment: You can stop Salesforce producing report footers see this https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_no_footer.htm

Comment: Customize > Reports & Dashboards> User Interface, then select Export Reports Without Footers

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your error, please check the below article. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206248&type=1
I would suggest trying with Dataloader.io http://dataloader.io/ , it is more reliable than dataloader.
Also try, Opening the file in excel, save as new CSV file.( It worked for me for a similar issue)

Comment: Dataloader.io is paid, i guess :)